# Drawing a quadrilateral inscribed within a circle

Tags: graphics, geometry

I would like to draw a quadrilateral inscribed within a circle. How can I construct this figure, taking into account arbitrary (specified) side lengths, while still ensuring that the vertices of the quadrilateral lie on the circle?

Comment: It is to be quad in a circle with a user-specified length of the side of a quad, is to change the circle to fit a quad in a circle.

Comment: Just that, given the length of the side of the square will fit within a circle, which is automatically size to fit the square.

Comment: I have edited your question according to what I *think* it means. Can you confirm whether or not this is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct Oleksandr R

Comment: A circle is defined by three (non-identical, not collinear) points. A fourth point cannot be arbitrarily chosen...

Comment: @OleksandrR. Inscribing is not compatible with hitting the vertices of the inscribed polygon...

Comment: Perhaps http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicQuadrilateral.html ?

Comment: @YvesKlett I know, but I couldn't deduce from the question how many side lengths are to be specified. I can't guess what the OP wants, so I only edited for comprehensibility, not necessarily logical consistency. :)

Comment: @OleksandrR. you´re between a rock and a hard place there :P

Comment: mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicQuadrilateral.html Yes 1 picture

Comment: @user5955 You image showed a rectangular inscribed. Therefore, I assumed you don't need an arbitrary quadrilateral.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly.
When you place your figure at {0,0}, meaning the center of the circle and the center of the rectangle is there, you don't need to calculate very much. Indeed, everything is then fixed by exactly one point `p` defining a corner of the rectangle and the radius of the circle.

A dynamic version of your graphics can be written down in only a few lines of code

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Thick], Rectangle[-p, p],
   Thick, Red, Circle[{0, 0}, Norm[p]]}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}],
 {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes thanks for your help. Best regards.