# How to draw Locator on circle[{m,n},r]?

Tags: locator

**I want to draw Locator on circle[{m,n},r].**

The follwing point p is free Locator. How to draw Locator on `Circle[{m,n},r]` ?

```
Manipulate[  
 Show[Graphics[ {Circle[o, r], 
                {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[o], Locator[Dynamic@o, None]},
                {PointSize[0.02], Blue, Point[p], Locator[Dynamic@p, None]} }]
      , Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 5],
 {{r, 1}, 0.5, 2, 0.1},
 {{o, {1, 1}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}, ControlType -> None},
 {{p, {2, 1}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}, ControlType -> None} ]
```

Comment: related q/a: [LocatorPane and PlotRange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6031/125)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Watch your manners! Add a `P`(lease)!

Comment: Closely related: [How to manipulate a circle in GeoGebra style?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5478) and [Drawing a quadrilateral inscribed within a circle](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19787/5478)

Comment: Related: [How to restrict the motion of a Manipulate-generated Locator along a line?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87440/18476)

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
p[c_, r_, pt_] := c + r  Normalize[pt - c];
DynamicModule[{pt = {3, 0}, c = {0, 0}, r = 3},
 Column[{
   Slider[Dynamic[r, (r = #; pt = p[c, r, pt]) &], {1, 3}],
   Graphics[{
     Dynamic@Circle[c, r],
     Locator[Dynamic[pt, (pt = p[c, r, #]) &]],
     Locator[Dynamic[c, (c = #; pt = p[c, r, pt]) &]]},
     Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 8]}]]
```

[image]